# Voltage divider to drive MOSFET gate

Tags: mosfet, switches, powermosfet

So I have two power rails of 48 and 54.6 V. The 54.6 V power rail is used to charge a battery. So the voltage on this rail varies according to CC and CV conditions. I want to use a P MOSFET as a switch to connect and disconnect the battery from this rail.
[image]

I am thinking of using the above setup (ignore the MOSFET part no) where the voltage from the voltage divider will drive the P MOS gate. Will this setup work, as I do not want to use gate driver IC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't work. More than likely the PMOS will never turn off because the gate-source minimum voltage is receives is -6.6 volts and that is sufficient to partially activate a lot of PMOS devices.

Why not take R1 to the 54.6 volt power rail instead of the 48 volt power rail?

Comment: Because the voltage on the 54.6V is not always 54.6,when charging the battery the voltage will vary between 42V to 54.6V. This in turn would vary the gate source voltage, so I thought it would be better to have a constant gate source voltage

Comment: No, the resistor needs to be connected to the source and, if the source is at 54.6 volts or 42 volts, that is where it needs to be connected to ensure full control @JustLiving

Comment: Ok got it so if I connect the resistor to 54.6 rail I can ensure full control of the P mosfet as a switch

Comment: It's the only sure way to achieve it. But, make sure you choose R1 and R2 so that you don't over-voltage the gate when trying to activate the MOSFET @JustLiving

Comment: should I employ a Zener diode as suggested below or is it ok if I skip it?

Comment: How quickly do you need to activate the mosfet?

Comment: not very quick,in under second would do

Comment: R1 and R2 will make a potential divider and, that can usually be enough to ensure that enough gate voltage is applied when the 2N7002 is activated. However, if the 54 volts can drop down to (say) 27 volts, the gate-source voltage will halve so, it's a bit of a juggle as to whether you need a zener diode to stop gate over-voltage when the potential divider ratio isn't as great @JustLiving

Comment: might be a basic question but the drain of the P mos would always be connected to the battery. The 54V rail will be powered on when we need to charge, otherwise it will be 0V.My understanding of mosfet is a bit confusing, but this shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: It will be a problem if the 54 volts goes to 0 volts rather than go open circuit.

Comment: I will be using a boost converter which drives a mosfet gate when enabled. When disabled the mosfet is off and there will be no voltage, how do I know if this is 0 volts or open circuit.

Comment: If your boost converter uses a diode in the output then it will look like an open circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in any case V<sub>GS</sub> of TP0610T is negative since its source is at 54V and its gate is at 48V. This makes V<sub>GS</sub> = -6V even when the 7002 is off and considering the fact that this MOSFET has low threshold (around -2V) the MOSFET will be on regardless of 7002's state.

Try this:

[image]

When the 2N7002 is off the gate and source of the TP0610T will be at the same potential which forces it to stay off. When the 2N7002 is on the gate will see a lower voltage so the TP0610T will be on. Note that V<sub>GS</sub> should be limited hence the Zener in parallel with R1. One potential problem here is that the breakdown voltage of 2N7002 is 60V which is quite close to 54.6V. You may want to consider using a different MOSFET.

Comment: The battery would be connected to J2 terminals. I would have to use different P mosfet as continuous current would be 3A. But the setup which you have modified will it do the function of connecting and disconnecting the battery from the charge rail(54.6V). The voltage on the 54.6V rail varies between 42V to 54.6V

Comment: @JustLiving doesn't matter. What matters is to make Vgs of the PMOS negative to turn it on, and zero or positive to turn it off. Regardless of the supply voltage it will work well.

Comment: @ Rohat Kılıç what value of Zener diode would you recommend for the Zener in parallel with R1